# Uneditable JavaScript code on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, readonly

I am doing an input check on an `<input type='text'/>` field using JavaScript / JQuery.

The problem: As far as I tried, you can edit JS code using the developer mode and change the JS code for the input check to always return true.

The question:
Is there a way to prevent the JS code from being changed such that the input check cannot be fooled, and is JS even a safe (not necessarely the safest) option here? Or would it be better to use PHP in this case?

Comment: You cannot actually edit a JS, but you can replace it with a local override. That's not something you can avoid. As stated by Wais, you can use server side code to assure the validation. If you wanna use JS on the server side, try node.js

Answer (score 5):

You cannot, in any way, hide JavaScript from the user. As you stated, you should use server-side technologies such as PHP, where the user will no longer be able to see or alter the processing involved.

A commonly used practice is to validate the entered data in the browser, and then revalidate it on the server, to ensure no altering of validation rules has been made by the user.

Comment: So it is impossible to make the JS file read-only and I should use PHP. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can make it harder, by doing `<script src="***"></script>`, but I aree there isn't a way to make it non editable.

Comment: Can you explain how it would be harder? I would just look it up in the "Sources" tab of the dev tools.

Comment: @WaisKamal I would think that you would have to go to the source, copy and paste into a new script, and then change it, and delete the old one, compared to just changing it.

Comment: Well on chrome you can just enter dev mode and edit the JS file in the sources tab, therefore altering the code and pretty much making any JS useless in any security application...